# How to subtract two dates in moment-jalaali on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript

The question is *How to subtract two jalaali dates in  moment-jalaali package on NodeJS?*. I cannot find any `subtract` for two dates on [their API](https://github.com/jalaali/moment-jalaali) in js.

Only related function is `subtract` which works for `jMonth`, `day` or `jYear`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no function up to now. However a trick can be using `subtract` likes the following:

```
 // m1: first day 1392/5/10 - m2 : second day 1387/3/2
 let m3 = m1.subtract(m2.jYear(), 'jYear');
 m3 = m3.subtract(m2.jMonth(), 'jMonth');
 m3 = m3.subtract(m2.jDate(), 'day');
```